# How to set key size for KeyPairGeneratorSpec on API 18?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-security

[Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) (with [`KeyPairGeneratorSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.html) etc) was introduced in API level 18. However, the method [`KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.setKeySize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.html#setKeySize(int)) was only introduced in API level 19.

While supporting API level 18 (Android 4.3), is it possible to set the key size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SupportedKeyPairGenerators), it would seem as though API level 18 does support different RSA `Key` sizes. But according to [another source](https://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html) (referencing API level 18):

> There is currently no way to specify key size or type and generated
>   keys default to 2048 bit RSA.

Though, I suppose you *should* be able to use a different [`AlgorithmParameterSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/spec/AlgorithmParameterSpec.html), such as the old [`RSAKeyGenParameterSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/spec/RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.html) available since API level 1; which takes a key size as a constructor argument:

```
keyPairGenerator.initialize(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(keySize, publicExponent));
```

Comment: Thanks! For my current needs "generated keys default to 2048 bit RSA" was all I had to know.